# The function is applied with three arguments

Tags: haskell

I need to create a list of tuples, each tuple represents a rectangle with (x, y, height,width).
With width constant, and I need to double the value of the height.

The output necessary:

```
> genRects 3 (0,0)
 [(0.0,0.0,5.5,5.5),(5.5,0.0,5.5,5.5),(11.0,0.0,5.5,5.5),(16.5,0.0,5.5,5.5)]
```

My Currently code:

```
genRects :: Int -> (Int,Int) -> [(Float,Float,Float,Float)]
genRects 0 _ = []
genRects n (x,y) = let height=5.5; width=5.5 in [(fromIntegral x, fromIntegral y, height, width)] genRects (n-1) (x+height, y)
```

Getting error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `(Int->(Int, Int)-> [(Float, Float, Float, Float)])
                                  -> Int -> (Int, Int) -> [(Float, Float, Float, Float)]'
                with actual type `[(Integer, Integer, Double, Double)]'
    The function `[(fromIntegral x, fromIntegral y, height, width)]'
    is applied to three arguments,
    but its type `[(Integer, Integer, Double, Double)]' has none
    In the expression:
      [(fromIntegral x, fromIntegral y, altura, comp)]
        genRects (n - 1) (x + x, y)
    In the expression:
      let
        height= 5.5
        width = 5.5
      in
        [(fromIntegral x, fromIntegral y, height, width)]
          genRects (n - 1) (x + x, y)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Also why is it going to double instead of Float?

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at

```
[(fromIntegral x, fromIntegral y, height, width)] genRects (n-1) (x+height, y)
```

That doesn't make sense. What you are trying to do is create one of the rectangles, and cons it on to all of the other rectangles, so you should use something like

```
(fromIntegral x, fromIntegral y, height, width): genRects (n-1) (x+height, y)
```

However, after making this change, you will see that

```
Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `Float'
In the second argument of `(+)', namely `height'
In the expression: x + height
In the second argument of `genRects', namely `(x + height, y)'
```

Which makes sense, you are trying to add a `Float` (5.5) to the x value, which you have said is an `Int`. The simplest solution is to use `Float`s for x,y, instead of `Int`s.
So you can change your code to,

```
genRects :: Int -> (Float,Float) -> [(Float,Float,Float,Float)]
genRects 0 _ = []
genRects n (x,y) = let height=5.5; width=5.5 in (x, y, height, width): genRects (n-1) (x+height, y)
```

And get the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

Any time you have a function which creates *n* of something where *n* is an explicit parameter to the function, ask yourself if you could instead write it as:

```
take n $ some_infinite_list
```

where `some_infinite_list` is an expression which creates an infinite list of the somethings.

For instance, here is the pattern of calls created by `genRects n (x,y)`:

```
genRects n (x,y)
  calls genRects (n-1) (x+h,y)     -- h = height
  calls genRects (n-2) (x+h+h, y)
  calls genRects (n-3) (x+h+h+h, y)
  ...
```

So if we start with the sequence:

```
xys = [ (x,y), (x+h, y),  (x+h+h, y), (x+3*h, y), ... ]
```

and create a function `to4Tuple`:

```
to4Tuple :: (Int,Int) -> (Float,Float,Float,Float)
```

mapping a pair (x,y) to your 4-tuple of floating point numbers, we can write `genRects` as:

```
genRects n (x0,y0) = take n $ map to4Tuple sys
  where xys = [ (x,y0) | x <- [x0, x0+h .. ] ]
        to4Tuple (x,y) = ...construct 4-tuple from x,y here...
```

Now you've avoided explicit recursion in the definition of `genRects`.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
[(fromIntegral x, fromIntegral y, height, width)] genRects (n - 1) (x + x, y)
```

you are applying a list to three arguments. Lists are not functions and cannot be applied like that. GHC is talking about `Double` because you've confused it and when it doesn't know what sort of floating point it's supposed to be dealing with, it defaults to `Double`.

Side note: unless you're dealing with algorithms specialty tuned for single precision floating point, or dealing with special library functions that require such, or using unboxed arrays of them to save on space, you should really be using `Double` in your code.